# Remove subdirectory and redirect 301

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, woocommerce, mailchimp

I use Wordpress, WooCommerce and MailChimp plugin, I think there's issue about  MailChimp plugin.

I found on Search Console a lot of 404 error, links like this:

/product-name/15df4gdfg4d5g4d56f

How can remove: 15df4gdfg4d5g4d56f

and write redirect on: /product-name/ ?

I think I need a rule because there are a lot 404 error

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to would use the [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin. It allows you to create [Regex](https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/) rules so that anything that matches `/product-name/*` redirects to `/product-name/`. Otherwise, you'd have to manually write rules to your `.htaccess` file.

The Redirection plugin also catches any 404s and allows you to create redirection rules based on those 404 errors.